# How To Set Up Irrlicht Game Engine in Xcode for ios deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, irrlicht

I know that some people have managed to do this, seeing as there are numerous apps on the app store powered by irrlicht. I have tried to set up an xcode project with all the irrlicht sources and compile and run for ios but can't get it to work. I am using irrlicht 1.7.3. Has anyone managed to do this who would be willing to share how they accomplished this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are using http://www.rtsoft.com/wiki/doku.php?id=proton

that uses irrlicht.

"Both 2D and 3D games (using the included but optional Irrlicht 3D engine) are supported."

Comment: I have explored that but couldn't get it to work. I did find an xcode project that combines irrlicht and bullet and runs successfully on ios. Here is the link: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34035&start=90

Comment: it seems the svn repository have changed. Any other alternative? :)